# slow order by "field" and limit

Tags: postgresql

I have simple query that must get 1 record from table with about 14m records:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "projects_toolresult"."id", 
"projects_toolresult"."tool_id", 
"projects_toolresult"."status",
"projects_toolresult"."updated_at",
"projects_toolresult"."created_at" FROM 
"projects_toolresult" WHERE 
("projects_toolresult"."status" = 1 AND 
"projects_toolresult"."tool_id" = 21)
 ORDER BY "projects_toolresult"."updated_at"
 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And it is weird that when I order query by `updated_at` field my query executes 60 sec.

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..510.94 rows=1 width=151) (actual
time=56754.932..56754.932 rows=0 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using projects_to_updated_266459_idx on projects_toolresult  (cost=0.43..1800549.09 rows=3527 width=151) (actual time=56754.930..56754.930 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((status = 1) AND (tool_id = 21))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 13709343  Planning time: 0.236 ms  Execution time: 56754.968 ms (6 rows)
```

No matter if it will be `ASC` or `DESC`

But if I do `ORDER BY RAND()` or without order:

```
Limit  (cost=23496.10..23496.10 rows=1 width=151) (actual time=447.532..447.532 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=23496.10..23505.20 rows=3642 width=151) (actual time=447.530..447.530 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (random())
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Index Scan using projects_toolresult_tool_id_34a3bb16 on projects_toolresult  (cost=0.56..23477.89 rows=3642 width=151) (actual time=447.513..447.513 rows=0 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (tool_id = 21)
               Filter: (status = 1)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 6097
 Planning time: 0.224 ms
 Execution time: 447.571 ms
(10 rows)
```

It working fast.

I have index on `updated_at` and `status` fields(I also tried without too). I did upgrade for default postgres settings, increased values with this generator: https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/

[image]

And this is what happens when this queries in action.

Postgres version **9.5**

My table and indexes:

```
id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('projects_toolresult_id_seq'::regclass)
 status          | smallint                 | not null
 object_id       | integer                  | not null
 created_at      | timestamp with time zone | not null
 content_type_id | integer                  | not null
 tool_id         | integer                  | not null
 updated_at      | timestamp with time zone | not null
 output_data     | text                     | not null
Indexes:
    "projects_toolresult_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "projects_toolresult_content_type_id_object_i_71ee2c2e_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content_type_id, object_id, tool_id)
    "projects_to_created_cee389_idx" btree (created_at)
    "projects_to_tool_id_ec7856_idx" btree (tool_id, status)
    "projects_to_updated_266459_idx" btree (updated_at)
    "projects_toolresult_content_type_id_9924d905" btree (content_type_id)
    "projects_toolresult_tool_id_34a3bb16" btree (tool_id)
Check constraints:
    "projects_toolresult_object_id_check" CHECK (object_id >= 0)
    "projects_toolresult_status_check" CHECK (status >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "projects_toolresult_content_type_id_9924d905_fk_django_co" FOREIGN KEY (content_type_id) REFERENCES django_content_type(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "projects_toolresult_tool_id_34a3bb16_fk_projects_tool_id" FOREIGN KEY (tool_id) REFERENCES projects_tool(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is, do you have any existing Python/Django code that you want to optimize?

Comment: Well it is what django ORM generates me. But I did this queries directly in postgres console. I guess i need to remove django tag

Comment: Looks like you need to add an index to the `updated_at` column.

Comment: You are filtering on `status` and `tool_id`, and sorting on `updated_at`. Add an index with those 3 fields.

Comment: @Nicarus I updated my answer and show you indexes

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have index on updated_at

Comment: @Arti - Where is there a single index on all 3 of those columns?

Comment: @Nicarus oh, even need like this. I will try

Comment: @Nicarus wow, you were right. It is weird, when I created index only for status and updated_at because thought that I have already tool_id index and it didn't work

Comment: PostgreSQL can't use the `(status, updated_at)` index when you include another column (`tool_id`) to the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filtering your data on `status` and `tool_id`, and sorting on `updated_at` but you have no single index for all three of those columns.

Add an index, like so:

`CREATE INDEX ON projects_toolresult (status, tool_id, updated_at);`